# How to set object property inside of function

Tags: javascript, object

I declare two object with name,link and page properties. After receiving data from Twitch API, I add a property status to my objects, which works inside the function, but leaving it I can't access status property anymore. I even tried to set the status property using getApi to return the status as streamer0.status=getApi(); but it does not work either.

```
    var streamer0={name:"freecodecamp"};   
    streamer0.link='https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'+streamer0.name;                    streamer0.page='https://www.twitch.tv/'+streamer0.name;
    var streamer1={name:"famasfordemacia"};  
    streamer1.link='https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'+streamer1.name;
    streamer1.page='https://www.twitch.tv/'+streamer1.name;
    var link="";
    $(document).ready(function(){
    load();
    function load(){
       for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
          {
          switch(i){
             case 0:{ 
                  link=streamer0.link;
                  getApi(streamer0);
                  console.log(streamer0.status) //it does not work
                  break;
                    }
             case 1:{ 
                  link=streamer1.link;
                  getApi(streamer1);
                  console.log(streamer1.status) //it does not work
                  break;
                  } 
          } 
    }
function getApi(x){
   $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: link,
   headers: {
  'Client-ID': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
          },
       success: function(data) {
           if(data["stream"]==null)
              {
               x.status="offline";
               console.log(x.status)//works
              }
            else
              {
               x.status="online";
              }
            }
         });
        }
  });
```

Comment: It's because $.ajax behaves asynchronously. In essence, console.log(streamer0.status) happens before the success function does.

Comment: Fast, but not the best solution: add into ajax options `async: false`

Answer (score 1):

You are Using Ajax , its asynchronous , so you have three options :

1 - put all you code inside the success callback which will be a big miss.

```
function getApi(x) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: link,
        headers: {
            'Client-ID': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // ALL YOUR CODE IN HERE

        }
    });
}
```

2 - Using a callback function :

```
function getApi(x, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: link,
        headers: {
            'Client-ID': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // PASS YOUR DATA YOU THE CALL BACK
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}

// THEN USE IT IN THE LOAD FUNCTION AS THE FOLLOWING

function load(){
    for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        switch(i){
            case 0:{
                link=streamer0.link;

                getApi(streamer0,function(data){
                    console.log(data.status) //it does not work
                });

                break;
            }
            case 1:{
                link=streamer1.link;
                getApi(streamer1,function(data){
                    console.log(data.status) //it does not work
                });
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

3 - is using Promise (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Answer (score 0):

It is a asynchronous call so you need wait until the call is done,

`function getApi(x) {
    return $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: link,
    headers: {
    'Client-ID': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' }});`

```
case 0:{ 
        link=streamer0.link;
         getApi(streamer0).success(function(data){
          if(data["stream"]==null)
          {
           streamer0.status="offline";
           console.log(streamer0.status)//works
          }
        else
          {
           streamer0.status="online";
          }
        }
        console.log(streamer0.status) //it does not work
     });
       break;
   }
```

hope It helps you, :)